# tsconfig.json is not reacting to path property update

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

This is what a problematic block of imports that I got:
[image]

This is my tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "jsx": "react" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react', 'react-jsx' or 'react-jsxdev'. */,
    "noEmit": true /* Do not emit outputs. */,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "baseUrl": "./" /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./react/Components/*"],
      "@config": ["./config.json"],
      "@endpoints": ["./react/Endpoints/*"],
      "@lib": ["./lib/*"],
      "@resources": ["./resources/*"],
      "@helpers/*": ["./react/Helpers/*"],
      "@screens/*": ["./react/Screens/*"],
      "@redux/*": ["./react/Redux/*"]
    },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,

    "experimentalDecorators": true /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */,

    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": ["./types/*", "react"]
}
```

And this is my babel config json:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo", '@babel/preset-typescript'],
    plugins: [
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: ['.'],
          extension: [
            '.js',
            '.jsx',
            '.ts',
            '.tsx',
          ],
          alias: {
            "@components": "./react/Components",
            "@helpers": "./react/Helpers",
            "@screens": "./react/Screens",
            "@redux": "./react/Redux",
            "@config": "./config.json",
            "@endpoints": "./react/Endpoints",
            "@lib": "./lib",
            "@resources": "./resources",
            "@components/*": "./react/Screens/*",
            "@helpers/*": "./react/Helpers/*",
            "@screens/*": "./react/Screens/*",
            "@redux/*": "./react/Redux/*"
          }
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

I have tried to rebuild/to reopen vsCode/to restart TS server but nothing has helped. Looking for a way to turn `tsconfig.json` in power, cause its not reacting on tsconfig updates

Comment: It seems like your baseUrl is wrong and it should be "./src" instead of "./". Try that and reload your vscode.

Answer (score 0):

The `baseUrl` in the `compilerOptions` informs the compiler where to find your modules and it seems your modules live in the `src` folder and not in the root `./` which is why the compiler cannot find them because it is looking for them in the wrong place, outside the src folder.

Comment: I don't actually have an `src` folder

Comment: @AlexUA Did you find the solution ?